# Python script for creating Space on Cloud Confluence

Tags: confluence-rest-api

I have over 700 Projects for which I have to create Spaces on Confluence Cloud. Doing this manually is not feasible. Have to come up with some script or tool that reads the information from Text File and creates the spaces. I have programming background - Python and Java. Can someone suggest a solution for achieving this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code snippet for reading the space and page names from excel and creating them in Confluence cloud -

```
import requests
import json
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from collections import defaultdict

filename = "path/PjtExport.xlsx"
wb = load_workbook(filename)
sheet = wb["Sheet1"]
confdict = defaultdict(list)

for i1 in range(2,10) :
    if(str(sheet.cell(row=i1, column=1).value) != "None") :
        spaceName = str(sheet.cell(row=i1, column=1).value)
        keyName = spaceName.replace(" ","")
        #print(keyName)
        if not(confdict.keys().__contains__(spaceName)):
            confdict.setdefault(keyName,spaceName)
            #print(spaceName)

            url = 'https://domain.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/space'
            auth = HTTPBasicAuth('xxx@yyy.com', 'abcabcabc')

            headers = {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
            payload = json.dumps({
                "key": keyName,
                "name": spaceName,
                "description": {
                    "plain": {
                        "value": "Test space created in Python - XL Int",
                        "representation": "storage"
                    }
                },
            })
            response = requests.request(
               "POST",
               url,
               data=payload,
               headers=headers,
                auth=auth
            )
            res_data = response.json()
            spaceID = str((res_data["homepage"]["id"]))
            pageName = str(sheet.cell(row=i1, column=2).value)

            url = "https://domain.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/content/aaaa/pagehierarchy/copy"
            auth = HTTPBasicAuth('xxx@yyy.com', 'abcabcabc')
            headers = {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
            payload = json.dumps({
                "copyAttachments": True,
                "copyPermissions": True,
                "copyProperties": True,
                "copyLabels": True,
                "copyCustomContents": True,
                "destinationPageId": spaceID,
                "titleOptions": {
                    "prefix": pageName + "  ",
                    "replace": "",
                    "search": ""
                }
            })
            response = requests.request(
                "POST",
                url,
                data=payload,
                headers=headers,
                auth=auth
            )
            page_data = response.json()
            #spaceID = str((res_data["homepage"]["id"]))

            print(page_data)
```